# Localhost to AWS Lambda No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Header

Tags: cors, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I have a local server that I am using to test the communication of a future remote hosted server and its communication to a Lambda serverless API. The request I am making to the API is a GET method and I have the following configured at the moment to handle the cross-site communication.

Using the serverless framework, I enabled `cors: true` in the `serverless.yml` file

In addition, the response is set to return the following:

```
response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET'
        },
        "body": {
            "message": "Authorization Successful!"
        }
    }
```

However a link click from a `http://localhost:8000` to my API hosted at `https://*id*.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/auth` delivers an error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://*id*.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Should I be adding headers to the GET when I fetch this API when a link is clicked on localhost:8000? Do I need to update anything with this `AWS API Gateway`? From the serverless framework documentation it sounded like `cors: true` would take care of this setup

Answer (score -1):

Have you deployed the API Gateway? Make sure in API Gateway you select the GET Method and under the action dropdowns select deploy. A CORS issue can be debunked by seeing if you are able to reach the API Gateway from Postman, but not the browser. Since you are returning Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*" the browser will allow the request.